# Uploading data to Firebase with "IF" and UIPickerController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

I started coding a few weeks ago and I am trying to load data to my Firebase.database for my app. But the thing is, that I want the data to load/save into different folders/names ("A" & "B") in my database in firebase so that later i can retrieve the data on 2 different scroll views with one scroll view only showing "A" and one only showing "B".

My code is not throwing errors at me, but for some reason it won't upload data. i don't know why it is not working.

Help highly appreciated.
Thanks community !!

Code incoming !

---

/// Picker now

```
// 2 items for the picker.
var data = ["A", "B"]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    // Column count: use one column.
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
                numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    // Row count: rows equals array length.
    return data.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
                titleForRow row: Int,
                            forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    // Return a string from the array for this row.
    return data[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    true
}
```

---

```
//Here I try to Upload the image that I picked in UIPickerView

@IBAction func Upload(sender: UIButton){

    func simplePicker(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if component == 0 {

            func Upload(){
            _ = UIImage.self
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().childByAutoId().setValue("A")
            }}

        if component == 1 {

            func Upload(){
            _ = UIImage.self
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().childByAutoId().setValue("B")
            }}


    }

}
```

Comment: Try printing something before `FIRDatabase.database().ref...` in each block and see your console gets some output.And why are you creating a function inside the if block `func Upload()`

Comment: I do not think that texts like "CODE INCOMING !!!" are necessary for the question.

Comment: Thank you @Dravidian, but sadly it is not working.
I deleted "fun Upload" and tried printing before the "FIR.Reference".
I am still not getting any results.

Comment: .childByAutoId() -- always creates new child in database. Remove it and try again

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I managed to find a way. I will Post the solution that worked for me. Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Cheers, Leo

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if row == 0 {FIRDatabase.database().reference().childByAutoId().setValue("A")}

    if row == 1 {FIRDatabase.database().reference().childByAutoId().setValue("B")}
}
```

P.s. The Problem was the phrasing. It is not components. It is "rows" !

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
var valueToStore : String = "Placeholder"

@IBAction func Upload(sender: UIButton){

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().childByAutoId().setValue(valueToStore)
       //Storing the values the value you want to store ..
}


func simplePicker(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if component == 0 {
         valueToStore = "A" 
      }else if component == 1 {
         valueToStore = "B"}

  //Setting the value you want to store in a global variable..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but now it simply Uploads the data as "Placeholder".
I am going to try put the "var" inside the if- statements.

Comment: Wont help...Reason why its uploading `Placeholder` because either your  `simplePicker(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` doesnt gets called or `component ` values is neither 0 or 1

Comment: Okay... so what do I do ? :S

Comment: Try printing component in the first line of `simplePicker(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` or if you know how to use breakPoints check if the call ever went to that block

Comment: I honestly do not really know what you mean.
I am still a beginner in swift and coding in general.